# Automatic Partitioning in Oracle11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have a table with a huge volume of data. I need partitioning to be done on a daily basis automatically. I need the name of the partition to be the date of sysdate. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

There is currently (11gR2) no way to specify a name for the auto-generated partitions in an interval-partitioned table. See [Common Questions On Interval Partitioning [ID 1479115.1]](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1479115.1) (Oracle support account required):

> **What will be the names of the automatically created interval partitions?**
>
> [...] Currently it is not possible to specify a mask or template for partition names, but the system generated name can be renamed [...]

You're also restricted to a partition key column which must be of type `DATE` or `NUMBER`, and a few other things (see that note).

You can follow the example in the [Creating Partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE) documentation for the syntax:

```
create table foo (date_created date, ...)
  partition by range(date_created)
  interval(numtodsinterval(1, 'DAY'))
  (partition one values less than (to_date('01012013', 'DDMMYYYY')));
```

With the above, a new partition will be created whenever you insert a row with a date value this year or later. New partitions will **not** be created for dates before 2013.

To work around the partition name issue (if necessary at all), you could rename the partitions based on `HIGH_VALUE` in `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS`, although that doesn't sound very nice.
Another option is to not rename them at all and use this syntax when you want to query a specific partition:

```
select *
from foo
partition for (<the day you're interested in>);
```

See for example: [Oracle Interval Partitioning Tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interval_partitioning.htm).

Comment: I am sorry , I forgot to give one information . In my table I don't have any column which has the current date. In that case, can I do the partioning on the basis of (SYSDATE). I want the partition to be done on the basis of when data was inserted into the table.

Comment: You need to add a column for the date then. There's no alternative. You could imagine a computed column for the partitioning but that won't work for what you're trying to do.